# How to stop jquery autocomplete spinner if AJAX error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When AJAX raises a timeout event, the loading spinner keeps on spinning.

```
    $("#mySearchField").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 300,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/query",
                data: { first: $('#mySearchField').val() },
                success: response,
                timeout: 3000
            });
        }
    });
```

How can I stop the spinner?

Comment: Not sure what spinner you're talking about, but you can add the error callback and perform whatever actions needed to stop the spinner (Does it have a boolean attached to it?) 
Just add error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }

Comment: We need more details about your spinner. is it an css animated spinner? a gif? what is the css identifier of this spinner?

Comment: The spinner is similar as here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote by using //code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css and code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js. If AJAX is sucessful, then the spinner stops automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in both success and complete method will resolve this issue.

```
$("#textboxid").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
```